# parameter value in match xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters, xslt-1.0

I want to use parameter value in xpath of xsl select to replace text. But, the value not getting replaced.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:id="1" w:rsidR="00041C05" w:rsidRDefault="00EA4F36">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>value1</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00041C05" w:rsidSect="00041C05">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
exclude-result-prefixes="w"
>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:param name="replacement">
        new value
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="id">1</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:template match='w:p[@w:id="$id"]/w:r/w:t/text()'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$replacement" />
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:id="1" w:rsidR="00041C05" w:rsidRDefault="00EA4F36">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>value1</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00041C05" w:rsidSect="00041C05">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

`<w:t>value1</w:t>` should replaced to `<w:t>new value</w:t>` .
[Code](http://xsltransform.net/jxN9j98)

Comment: Your predicate contains the boolean expression `@w:id="$id"` which checks if the `w:id` attribute has the literal string value "`$id`". Try `@w:id=$id` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"$id"` is a string literal for the string `$id`. It's not a variable/parameter reference.

You can't use a variable/parameter reference in a `match` expression in XSLT 1.0, so I think your best bet would be to check within the `xsl:template` whether the text node is the one you're looking for:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
exclude-result-prefixes="w"
>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:param name="replacement">
        new value
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="id">1</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:template match='w:p/w:r/w:t/text()'>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test='../../../@w:id = $id'>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replacement" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```